# VSCode GUI theming: How to slim down pane tabs?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Hi,
Is it possible to make the tabs shorter?
In the theme I'm working in, the way they look by default they are too tall and look out of place.

I already looked into VSCode settings but couldn't find any property associated to their height.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible. You cannot customize *every* aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. As of VS Code 1.19, you cannot customize the height of the tabs using a theme

This type of customization would probably fall under [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/459)